# Detect the presence of Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant 1.2.1 in a site visitor's browser

Tags: javascript, .net, firefox, clickonce

I need to detect if a user has the Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant 1.2.1 installed on their browser when they visit my site because I am making use of Microsoft's ClickOnce installer technology. This is a Firefox plugin. I've tried detecting it using navigator.plugins in JS but it's not coming back with anything useful. Is there some other way to detect the add-on's presence in a user's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the user-agent string.
It will end with something like `( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)`